# Deserialize binary data without knowing the exact type written

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I've encountered a problem where a small number of data objects stored using a `BinaryFormatter` are coming back with parameters missing (null/default).

I'd like to know if the missing items were saved as null, or if the objects that were serialized were changed from the versions in source control and then reverted before a code commit (eg `int numDogs` vs `unsigned int dogCount`).

The former would represent a serious bug in the data validation code ran before the serialization was done; while the latter is just junk data in a test DB and ignorable.

Since the `BinaryFormatter` is able to get everything else out when a member is changed, added, or removed I assume it's writing objects in a form similar to a key value store.  Is there any way to get a human readable representation of it, without having to try and guess the exact details of the object that was serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) on your objects, you can have a look at what's been serialized by trying to deserialize.

You will need to add a constructor with the same signature as `ISerializable.GetObjectData` - this is where deserialization occurs.

Comment: The example code in MSDN is for doing non-standard behavior.  This site has an example of a conventional implementation:    http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-streams/how-to-implement-iserializable-the-serialization-constructor-and-the-getobjectdata-method/

Comment: the original link in my comment's dead, but it was archived on the Wayback Machine:  https://web.archive.org/web/20170622134922/http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-streams/how-to-implement-iserializable-the-serialization-constructor-and-the-getobjectdata-method/